# Custom ThreadPoolTaskExecutor doesn't work with @Async

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I saw a piece of code from my company, and it's using `@HystrixCommand` for an async operation and returning an instance of Netflix's `AsyncResult`. I am trying to return a CompletableFuture instance instead of AsyncResult. (The reason I am doing this is just to experiment and see if they are interchangeable. Also CompletableFuture is native Java.)

Code sample:

```java
    @HystrixCommand(commandKey = MY_COMMAND,
                    threadPoolKey = MY_KEY,
                    ignoreExceptions = MyException.class)
    public Future<MyResponse> computationTaskAsync(){

        return new AsyncResult<MyResponse>() {
            @Override
            public MyResponse invoke() {
                MyResponse response = downStreamConnector.getProducts(); // the async operation
                return response;
            }
        };
    }
```

So this will work:

```java
    @Async
    public Future<MyResponse> computationTaskAsync(){
        MyResponse response = downStreamConnector.getProducts(); 
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(response);
    }
```

But when I specify my own executor as `@Async("myExecutor")`, it doesn't work. The problem is when I call get() on the future object, it doesn't block and wait for the result but instead throws an NPE immediately. The async operation is being done after the NPE thrown.

Here is what my config for Executor look like:

```java
@Configuration
public class AsyncConfig {
    @Bean("myExecutor")
    public Executor myExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(10);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(20);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(200);
        executor.setKeepAliveSeconds(60);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("myExecutor-");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }
}
```

I tried auto wired the executor bean as a data member of the class and checked the bean with debugger, and I saw that it was successfully wired in at them time when I call the async method.

All the resources I could find online suggest that this would work. I have no idea why it isn't working. Can you please help?

Comment: Did you add `@EnableAsync`?

Comment: In the main method, yes.

Comment: Maybe it's your method returning `null` or `downStreamConnector` is `null`. Try returning constant value to debug

Comment: The downstream is returning something with both```@Async``` or ```@Async("myExecutor")``` annotations. The problem is the caller doesn't wait when I call get() when the callee is annotated with ```@Async("myExecutor")```. It is doing its work but only after the NPE is thrown.

Comment: hi @Andy I did call ```executor.initialize()``` in the code base. Just forgot to include this when typing here. I will update it. Appreciate your help folks.

Comment: Does implementing `org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.AsyncConfigurer` behave correctly?